# Zk-snark range proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

The task is something like this. Alice must send Bob the money, but so that the amount remains hidden.

How can this be done if only "**hiding**" balances are stored in the **blockchain**? How can I prove to someone that my balance is positive after the transfer?

In other words, how can I prove to someone that the number **x >0**, if the person only knows the "hiding" of this number, say, **g^x**, where g is the generator of some elliptic curve? Prove without revealing x.

I know how snarks are constructed: **R1 CS-> AP -> weil pairing**, I know how this problem would be solved if x were known and not hidden.

For example, we represent **x = sum(u_i*2^i)** write in R1 CS another u_i u_i = u_i and thus prove that all u_i = 0 or 1

What's next? some very simple dumb guy. if x was known, we would have written it just in R1 CS as a public input and would have quietly checked something like

```
v2 = u1*1+u2*2 
v3 = v2+u3*2^2
 ... 
vn = u_(n-1) + u_n*2^(n-1)
```

and would add public input vn = x

and so what to do?

Comment: it is too easy or too hard? :)